# RoR: Using a method defined in user model in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in RoR and hoping you experts can help me on this. Apologies in advance if my question sounds weird or stupid. Let me know if you need more clarification, thanks so much in advance.

I have a boolean method called is_pollie (set default to false) in the user model which I want to change it to true once a user completed a form in a different controller called profiles_controller.rb.

Now, I have a user model with a defined method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :profiles

def self.is_pollie?
is_pollie
end
```

And in a different controller called profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

def create

@pollie = User.is_pollie?

@profile = current_user.profiles.build(profile_params)
if @profile.save
  # what should I put here if I want the is_pollie? to change to true upon
  a user click the save button on the form? 
  redirect_to basic_profile_path(@profile)
else
  flash[:alert] = "Oh no, something went wrong."
  render :new
end

end
```

In the page where the form is:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Displayed name:</label>
<%= f.text_field :display_name,class: "form-control"%>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope you understand my question and are able to help. Thanks very much again.

Comment: Try `current_user.update(is_pollie: true)`

Comment: Dear jvillian, YOU are my hero! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Added as answer along with some comments. Feel free to upvote/accept as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
current_user.update(is_pollie: true)
```

BTW, a couple of other points...

This:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :profiles

  def self.is_pollie?
    is_pollie
  end

end
```

doesn't make any sense because `self` makes `is_pollie?` a class method. But, `is_pollie` is an instance value.

Also, you don't even need `is_pollie?` because you can use do `current_user.is_pollie` which will return `true` of `false`.

Finally, you're not using `@pollie = User.is_pollie?` anywhere, so why do it?

Comment: You are amazing jvillain. With one quick look, you understood everything. Hoping to be like you one day. Thanks for the extra points too, I understand this better now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `current_user.update_column(:is_pollie, true)`

update method will trigger the call_backs, it's recommended to use update_column for updating a selected attribute.

For multiples you can use `update_columns(attributes1: value, attributes2: value)`

Comment: Thank Nithil for your response - really appreciate it!